# SocketException on wrong thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, udp, udpclient, socketexception

I am using the C# `UdpClient` class to to UDP networking. There is one `UdpClient` object, bound to a fixed local port, but not to any remote endpoint, because it needs to be able to send/receive to/from multiple different endpoints.

I have two threads: One for sending, one for receiving. Now, when I send data to an endpoint that exists, but doesn't listen on that port, I expect a `SocketException`. And I do get one. Unfortunately, it is not my `Send` call that returns the exception, but the `Receive` call. So on my sending thread, I send data to an "invalid" endpoint, and my receiving thread gets the exception. Unfortunately, at that point, I have of course no idea what endpoint caused that exception to happen.

Storing the endpoint before sending, then accessing that in the receiving thread is just a race condition error waiting to happen.

Unfortunately, the `SocketException` does not give me the endpoint that caused the error.

Any ideas? Is it somehow possible to make the exception be thrown on the sending thread?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is more or less by design because of how UDP works. Assuming it can send data i.e. initialized correctly. I believe this because UDP does not do any error checking. It simple Sends and Forgets.

Comment: I could live with that, if it wouldn't kill my Receive()-call. Somehow, this seems pretty illogical.

Comment: So reader closer to the Documentation, it might be something else. Can you post the SocketException and SocketException.ErrorCode to better help you.

Comment: @Callash, the logic is that normally when you `send()` to a remote host and you don't know if the remote host is listening, you're a *client*, and the `recv()` call is when you would *expect* to see the error (due to UDP's asynchronous nature). It sounds like you're developing a server or peer-to-peer app, which doesn't quite fit this use case. In your case it seems like you should catch and ignore the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `send()` a UDP packet, it goes out on the wire and effectively disappears.  You should not assume that you will get any feedback at all.

Sometimes, if there is no listener at the destination, the destination *might* be kind enough to send back an `ICMP_UNREACH_PORT` message.  The routers in between then *might* be kind enough to deliver that message to your operating system.  If that happens, it will be long after your original `send()` call returned.  For `ICMP_UNREACH_PORT`, the OS typically caches it and reports an error the next time yo do a `send()` to the same destination.  Other ICMP messages (you didn't mention which exception you are getting) could affect other calls.

So the bottom line is that there's no telling when, or if, UDP errors will be reported.  It depends on a lot of variables.  So be prepared to handle exceptions on any call, and be prepared for packets to just disappear without any error reported.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is expected behavior for UDP. A UDP `send()` is not a blocking operation, so it won't wait for a potential error. (Not to mention the fact that you can't rely on the error messages being reliably received when sending to an active host with a closed port - it could be firewalled, rate-limited or otherwise dropped due to congestion, etc.)

You can `connect()` the UDP socket to a specific remote endpoint, which would allocate a unique port number and allow the OS to [most likely] distinguish errors from that specific endpoint from any other random host. But again, you should not rely on the ability to handle these errors.

It's too bad there isn't more information in the exception. This seems like an oversight in the way .NET handles UDP sockets. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive.aspx), you need to check the exception's ErrorCode and handle the [error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) appropriately. (which, in your case, could likely mean ignoring the error.)